# How to deploy .net core application to webserver such as someee.com

Tags: asp.net, .net, .net-core, deployment, hosting

I'm trying to deploy my website to a free server (someee.com),
My application is code first (Using migrations), and this is the Github link for the site: https://github.com/mohamedvoli/ToDo/tree/main/TodoList

I've published the website with all options (Win x84 / Win x64) - (Self-contained / Target Framework) but it's not working and giving me this error :

```
This page isn’t working right nowtodolist.somee.com can't currently handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 503
```

and I didn't upload any database files and I don't know whether I should do it or not because it's a code-first approach, I'm a beginner and I don't know what to do with this problem really I would appreciate it if anyone could help me with that.

Comment: Does it really have to be someee? Microsoft's own Azure is more integrated with VS and the free tier is enough for small apps

Comment: Really? Could I deploy the app to Azure for free? It's he first time to know that, I'll search about how to use it as free hosting for my app, Thanks a lot

Comment: But, you have to use your credit card while registering for Azure. Keep that in mind. Although they won't charge for free trier, but they will ask for it if you use any paid service.

Comment: As I looked on somee.com, and they support ASP.NET Core 3.1...so what version you are using?

Comment: What about your database ? Have you provided correct connection string to some non-local db ? Also, setup logging to file - it'll probably tell you why your application can't start. There's no difference if you host your application on Azure or somee if your configuration is wrong.

Comment: @Ankush jain Thanks a lot for the hint, and i'm using .Net 5.0

Comment: @posio yeah this is what i wanna know, In the local level i'm setting the connection string in appsettings.json, but after publishing the app the project structure becoming completely different, so where should i configure the connection string, and could give me more hints about the logging file or any kind of related doc explaining it.